# TYPO3 secure_downloads does not work under https?

Tags: security, download, typo3

I tested the TYPO3 extension secure_downloads on development site, and it worked fine. When I installed it with identical settings on the production server, which  uses HTTPS, it failed to generate the secure links.

This is under TYPO3 6.2 LTS, and version 2.0.3 of the extension.

I thought that the extension https_enforcer might be an issue, but the problem persists after removing that.

Thank you.

Comment: You will find a documentation here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/secure_downloads . Looking at the list of authors, i am quite sure there is a solution for that.
Will post that one on Slack.

Answer (score 0):

In the extension configuration, you can force the HTTPS by configuring
Parsing | Domain [basic.domain]
to the full https://example.com/

While that setting is supposedly "not needed for internal (relative) links," it is needed if you want to always use a secure connection.